# Declaring transparency-varied colour primary in XML without explicitly declaring each colour resource

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a colour resource below:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#546e7a</color>
```

I want to set this color resource as the color of many text types of my customized themes. However, on each theme, I may want to alter the transparency value (i.e. the `a` in `rgba`) of my colour resource. If possible, I do **not** want to redefine a new colour resource like below (simply because I might use a lot of different transparency values):

```
<color name="colorPrimary12Percent">#1FD81B60</color>
```

Is there some sort of function in XML that can alter the transparency of a colour resource value given the colour resource and the transparency value (e.g. `rgba(colorResourceValue, transparencyValue)`)? An example of what I want to do with said function:

```
<style name="SomeNewStyle" parent="InheritFromThis">
    <item name="android:textColor">rgba(@color/colorPrimary, 12%)</item> <!-- This is what I want -->
</style>
```

Comment: Themes and style are static you can't change theme at runtime, try another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList). You can find a useful description in [Android Styling: Prefer Theme Attributes](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-styling-prefer-theme-attributes-412caa748774).

A *ColorStateList* can do the combining of the text color and the alpha value by theme/style as follows:

Define a custom attribute that will hold the alpha value:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyAttrs">
        <attr name="textAlpha" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Define the *ColorStateList*:

```
<selector>
    <item android:alpha="?attr/textAlpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

Put it all together in styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="textAlpha">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/color_state_list_example</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change the color by style and not use *colorPrimary*, you can define an additional attribute to hold the color like the one for the alpha value.

Comment: That's a really great link. I ended up reading all his posts about theming and styling. Thanks, exactly what I needed.